# How to add notes spaces with beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm currently preparing a small presentation with `beamer`. No problems so far.

Except that I'm looking for the best manner to get notes space (1/2 slides) like it's possible to do with Powerpoint or such tools. So that I can print my slides and add custom notes on the right. (i.e something better than `\frame[plain]{}` after each slide)

About the look if I wasn't clear enough :

[image: Slides with notes]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [`handoutWithNotes`](https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes/blob/master/handoutWithNotes.sty) package.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{3 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
My first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Second one
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Third
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives you (with the `Berlin`) theme:

[image]

You can find some examples here: http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/

I didn't find this package on CTAN. So it won't be in your LaTeX distribution and you need to install it manually.